# Error: expected a ";" when linking a static library

Tags: c++, linker

I have a library that need to be linked with my application. Code are written in Visual Studio 2015, and I do not have the source to the library. It was given by a company to me to compile the library into my application so I can interact with their hardware.

Upon adding the header file intellisense throw me a bunch of errors. [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylnvJ.png)

Really need some help here.

Below are some configuration I've done.

1. Add the linker additional directories to my .lib file path.`C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Safebox\Lib`

> /OUT:"C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Safebox\Win32\Debug\Safebox.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Safebox\Win32\Debug\Safebox.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "qtmaind.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5Sqld.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "GmpcFnc.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /PGD:"C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Safebox\Win32\Debug\Safebox.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\Safebox.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Safebox\Lib" /TLBID:1

2. Input the .lib file into the additional dependencies. 
   [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ElrV.png)
3. Add the additional include directories to the header file.`C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\`

   > /GS /analyze- /W1 /Zc:wchar_t /I".\GeneratedFiles" /I"." /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include" /I".\GeneratedFiles\Debug" /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtCore" /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtGui" /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtSql" /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtPrintSupport" /I"D:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets" /I"**C:\Users\liang\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects**" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "UNICODE" /D "WIN32" /D "QT_DLL" /D "QT_CORE_LIB" /D "QT_GUI_LIB" /D "QT_SQL_LIB" /D "QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB" /D "QT_WIDGETS_LIB" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Safebox.pch"

4.And added the header file

```
#include "../Include/GmpcFnc.h"
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with linking. It's an error in the source code somewhere, or possibly in the project's configuration.

Comment: "intellisense throw me a bunch of errors" - intellisense is not the compiler. That it complains does not mean the code will not compile. What errors does the the *actual* compiler generate?

Comment: These are the build error.       Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2146 syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'SetRdrPort' Safebox c:\users\liang\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\safebox\Include\GmpcFnc.h 36 
Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int Safebox c:\users\liang\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\safebox\Include\GmpcFnc.h 36

Comment: Anyway, I've found the solution, this library was make during 2006~2008, which does not include the <Windows.h> library, after adding the Windows.h, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, this library was make during 2006~2008, which does not include the  library, after adding the Windows.h, everything works fine.